# Is there a way to test which layout an Action Mailer email is rendered with?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, actionmailer

I have some Action Mailer email messages and I would like to test which layout will be used to render the email. I found [this example on the web](http://ryanbriones.com/blog/nerd/2008/10/23/testing-actionmailer-renders-template.html), but it's from 2008 and doesn't work with Rails 3.2 and presumably later versions.

My motivation for this is that I'd like to write a unit test that asserts that the mailer was rendered with a particular layout so if that is changed, the test will break.

Comment: Hey Luke. What about an assertion that renders the template with a layout set explicitly, and compares the text or HTML to what is generated (with whatever layout is currently specified)? My thought was that if someone changes the layout value in the mailer later, the test would fail. Didn't try this out, but I read this test and had that idea: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionmailer/test/base_test.rb#L545 That being said, it seems like there must be an instance variable with the layout name buried somewhere you could inspect (or add it as a patch).

Answer (score 3):

`ActionController::TestCase` has a method `assert_template`, so something like this should work:

```
class MailerTest < ActionController::TestCase
    ...
    def test_layout
      assert_template layout: "layout/something"
    end
    ...
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

Testing the layout rendered while sending emails can be done as part of the controller tests using `assert_template`.

Given the following mailer class and method,

```
class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base
  def password_reset_instructions(user)
    @user = user
    @reset_password_link = ...

    mail(to: ..., from: ...., subject: "Password Reset Instructions") do |format|
      format.html {render layout: 'my_layout'}
      format.text
    end
  end
end
```

the password reset email will be rendered using `my_layout.html.erb` layout.

This mailer method is likely to be invoked in a `UsersController` method, e.g.:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController


  def forgot_password
     user = ...
     Notifier.password_reset_instructions(user).deliver_now
  end

end
```

The `assert_template layout: "my_layout"` statement in the following controller test for `users_controller#forgot_password` would verify the layout used:

```
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  test "forgot password" do
    assert_difference 'ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.size', +1 do
      post :forgot_password, email: @user.email
    end 

    assert_response :redirect
    assert_template layout: "my_layout"
    assert_template "password_reset_instructions"

    password_reset_email = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
    assert_equal "Password Reset Instructions", password_reset_email.subject
  end
end
```

The relevant parts from the log:

```
Started POST "/users/forgot_password"
Processing by UsersController#forgot_password as HTML
...
  Rendered notifier/password_reset_instructions.html.erb within layouts/my_layout (1.1ms)
```

References:

1. [Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html)
2. [Testing Your Mailers - Functional Testing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-testing)
3. [assert_template method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TemplateAssertions.html#method-i-assert_template)